# nested ordered lists in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have observed a strange in nested ordered lists while using `rmarkdown`.

From [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#lists), the order of the numbers is ignored in the main list of items. Both of the below set produce the same output.

```
#set 1:
1.  one
2.  two
3.  three

#set 2:
5.  one
7.  two
1.  three
```

However, it is not the case in nested list of items.

```
#set 3:
1.  one
    5.  one
    7.  two
    1.  three
2.  two
3.  three
```

How to achieve automatic ordering of nested list of items in `rmarkdown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cf. the next section of the documentation (my emphasis):

> Pandoc also pays attention to the type of list marker used, and to the **starting number**, and both of these are preserved where possible in the output format.

To get the output you want (all new list should begin at 1.), disable the `startnum` extension ([source](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#markdown_extensions)):

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
     md_extensions: -startnum
---
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Some observations.
1. The tab space between the extension and parameter in nested lines.
2. This worked only if the above command is specified in the same Rmarkdown document. It didn't work while working with many documents for example while using the `bookdown` package where multiple Rmd documents can be stitched together.

Comment: I can't help you about bookdown, but afaik it is also using pandoc so there must be a way to disable the extension as well (in the raw pandoc call, it is done when one declares the output format `pandoc myfile.md -o myfile.html -t html-startnum`)